# Colocando itens em um array com Reactjs

Tags: javascript, array, react

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando colocar itens em um `array` ao clicar no botão, mas o mesmo esta iniciando vazio.Perceba que eu cliquei 3 vezes mas ele me mostra que o `array` tem 2 posições.

Eu tenho uma `div` que é o `display` essa `div` recebe o estado da constante `operation` que é um array. Ao clicar em em um botão é disparada um função chamada `addOperation(2)` com o valor 2, que coloca esse numero dentro do array.Estou utilizando `setOperation([...operation, value])` para empurrar o numero no `array`.

O problema é que ao clicar no botão o programa coloca o numero na segunda posição do array, e a primeira fica vazia, vocês sabem o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: A atualização de state é uma operação assíncrona. Uma das formas de pegar o valor atualizado é utilizar o useEffect. Aqui tem alguns exemplos: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Uma coisa importante, não coloque a imagem, só em determinados caso, nesse por exemplo que é código, coloque sempre o código.

Comment: Uma coisa se a minha resposta foi a solução do seu problema aceite como resposta e dê uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tenha noção de como funciona.

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo é que o seu `array` está sendo atualizado certo com as 3 posições criadas, mas, não mostra isso no `console.log` porque o `ReactJs` não atualizou seu componente, para que isso aconteça precisa utilizar o `useEffect` que no momento da atualização da variável o valor do novo `array` é mostrado, exemplo:

```js
function App() {
  const [operation, setOperation] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(operation);
  }, [operation]);
  function addOperation(value) {
      setOperation([...operation, value]);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={e => addOperation(2)}>Add</button>
      <ul>
        {operation.map((o,i)=>(<li key={i}>{o}</li>))}
      </ul>      
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

o `useEffect` nesse caso fica observando as alterações na variável e com isso mostra o valor correto das posições conforme a atualização do componente porque o estado [sempre é assíncrona](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: show deu certo.